# Read CSV, Change 2 Columns using pyproj Transform and save to new CSV

Tags: python, csv, latitude-longitude, transformer-model, pyproj

I'm very new to Python so apologies for my lack of understanding.

I need to read in 2 columns (latitude & longitude) of a 4 column CSV file.
**Example below.**

ShopName    Misc    latitude    longitude
XXX        3       999999      999999

I then have to change the latitude and longitude using a pyproj transform scrypt that I have checked. I then need to save the tranformed latitude and longitude data into a new csv such that the column format is the same as the existing csv.
**Example below.**

ShopName    Misc    latitude    longitude
XXX        3       49.12124    -2.32131

I'm a bit lost but this is where I got to. Thank you in advance

```
import csv
from pyproj import Transformer

#2.2 Define function
def transformer = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:12345", "epsg:9999")
    result = transformer.transform(old_longitude, old_latitude)
    return new_longitude, new latitude

#2.3 Set destination file to variable
with open('new.csv' ,'w') as csv_new2:

#2.4 Instruct write method to new file    
    fileWriter2 = csv.writer(csv_new2)
    
#2.5 Set existing file to variable
    with open('old.csv','r') as csv_old2:

#2.6 Instruct read method to new file
        fileReader2 = csv.reader(csv_old2)

        for row in fileReader2:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some options for you.

pandas + pyproj:

- [How to speed up projection conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61440619/how-to-speed-up-projection-conversion/61459700)

geopandas:

- https://geopandas.org/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html
- https://geopandas.org/projections.html

```py
from pyproj import Transformer
import pandas

pdf = pandas.read_csv("old.csv")
transformer = Transformer.from_crs("epsg:12345", "epsg:9999", always_xy=True)
xx, yy = trans.transform(pdf["longitude"].values, pdf["latitude"].values)
pdf = pdf.assign(longitude=xx, latitude=yy)
pdf.to_csv("new.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your code includes "...trans.transformer..." I needed to amend this to "...transformer.transform..." to make it work.   I am wondering also, some of the CSV data is blank and when I run the script it is adding 'inf' into the empty cells. Is there a way to make it not add anything?

Comment: That sounds like a separate question. I recommend asking a new question with your current progress.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your help.